# WebGL - Vertices don't render when assigning varying variable

Tags: html, glsl, webgl

My webgl program renders a white square, however whenever I try to pass a varying variable to the fragment shader it disappears, even if all the fragment shader does is: `gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

this renders nothing

```
   <script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        attribute vec3 vertexPos;
        attribute vec4 aColor;

        varying vec4 color;

        void main(void)
        {
            gl_Position = vec4(vertexPos, 1.0);
            color = aColor;
        }
    </script>
    <script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        precision mediump float;

        varying vec4 color;

        void main(void) 
        {
            gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        }
    </script>
```

this renders a white square

```
    <script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        attribute vec3 vertexPos;
        attribute vec4 aColor;

        varying vec4 color;

        void main(void)
        {
            gl_Position = vec4(vertexPos, 1.0);
            //color = aColor;
        }
    </script>
    <script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        precision mediump float;

        varying vec4 color;

        void main(void) 
        {
            gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: How are you setting up your attributes? If you hardcoded your attribute locations I'm guessing adding `aColor` changed the locations of the attributes and so you're not setting them up correctly.

Comment: @gman
cbuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cbo);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([0, 1, 1, 1]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

.... vertex data stuff.....

vertexColorAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(glProgram, "aColor");
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vertexColorAttribute);

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, rect.cbuffer);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(vertexColorAttribute, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

I hope it is slightly readable

Comment: @gman resolved it by making my color array 4 * 5 instead of 4 * 1

Comment: @TopkekMango: the usual StackOverflow method of marking question solved is to accept an answer. If you solved it yourself, write your solution into an answer and accept that.

Comment: @datenwolf It says I can't accept my own answer for another 2day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after reviewing my code I noticed that I only sent aColor to 1 out of the 5 vertices resolved it by making my color array 4 * 5 instead of 4 * 1

Comment: Did the you check the JavaScript console? Normally that would have given you an error in both Chrome and Firefox IIRC which would have helped you find the issue